# Nunit test config file being overwritten

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nunit

I have an Nunit test assembly called Tests. The associated configuration file is called Tests.dll.config. In VS2008 I have the Test.dll.config set "copy always". The problem is when I build the solution the Tests.dll.config file in the Debug or Release directory contains only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

The Tests.dll.config that has my settings in is not copied across.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix it. I added the following post-build event.

copy /Y “$(ProjectDir)Tests.dll.config” “$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config”